# Convert array of arrays to hash with first array's element as a key to the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.2

I want to convert this array

```
[['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'],['e', 'f']]
```

to this hash

```
{
  "a" : "c",
  "b" : "d"
},
{
  "a" : "e",
  "b" : "f"
}
```

How to do it?

I tried to use `group_by` and normal iterators but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Please do provide the code for fast response and assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
▶ arr = [[:a, :b],[:c, :d],[:e, :f],[:g, :h]]
▶ key, values = arr.first, arr[1..-1]
▶ values.map { |v| key.zip v }.map &:to_h
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#    :a => :c,
#    :b => :d
#  },
#  [1] {
#    :a => :e,
#    :b => :f
#  },
#  [2] {
#    :a => :g,
#    :b => :h
#  }
# ]
```

Please note that unlike other solutions presented here at the moment this one will map first element as keys to a tail of arbitrary length.

**UPD** For legacy rubies, not having `Array#to_h`:

```
values.map { |v| key.zip v }.map { |e| Hash[e] }
```

Comment: i was just trying it.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: A twist in the question, suppose if i have the set of 5 elements in an array instead of two and i want to ignore the first element of each array.?

Comment: Also can you please explain why you have taken the arr array from 1 to -1.? and why not [1..2] ?

Comment: @ahmadhamza This solution permits you to have as many elements in the hash as you want. To drop first one you’ll need to map result to `unshift` a first element. `[1..-1]` is there because the original array may be of any length.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
arr = [[:a, :b], [:c, :d], [:e, :f]]

arr.first.product(arr[1..-1]).map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:a=>:c, :b=>:d}, {:a=>:e, :b=>:f}]
```

If `arr` can be modified, we can write:

```
arr.shift.product(arr).map(&:to_h)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [["a", "b"],["c", "d"],["e", "f"]]
x[1..-1].map { |vs| {x[0][0] => vs[0], x[0][1] => vs[1]} }
```

Something like this.

Comment: This works on the array of exact length ≡ 3. In such a case it’s easier to build hash by hands.

Comment: @mudasobwa you're wrong- don't be confused of indexes [0] and [1] in the code. The code is correct.

Comment: @AndresEhrenpreis Oh, indeed. My eyes reject to look at hardcoded numeric indices while there are `first` and `zip` accessors.

Answer (score 1):

```
a= [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'],['e', 'f']]

a[1..-1].inject([]) { |sum, s| sum << {a[0][0] => s[0], a[0][1] => s[1]} }

=> [{"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d"}, {"a"=>"e", "b"=>"f"}]
```

improved：

```
a= [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['g', 'h', 'k']]
a[1..-1].inject([]) do |sum, s|
    hash = {}
    a[0].each_with_index { |it, i| hash.merge!({it => s[i]}) }
    sum << hash
end
=> [{"a"=>"d", "b"=>"e", "c"=>"f"}, {"a"=>"g", "b"=>"h", "c"=>"k"}]
```

This way is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

```
key = a.shift
p a.map{|x| key.zip(x).to_h } => [{"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d"}, {"a"=>"e", "b"=>"f"}]
```